# How to call a child function that calculates the memory address of the chosen row & column from array

Tags: arrays, c, memory

I'm having trouble trying to calculate the memory address, print the address, and the value of the chosen array element (by user input) in C.

I'm sure I have to use a pointer to the array and would prefer to use shift logical instead of multiplying.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// main calls child function
// child function calculates memory address of row & col
int main()
{
    // 2D array declaration
    // Initialize int array with 3 rows and 5 columns
    // [row][col]
    int arr[3][5] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
    };

    // Declare counter variables
    int i, j;

    // Loop through array to store values
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){

            // Ask user to input row and column
            printf("Enter row and column of your choice[%d][%d]:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Display elements of array
    printf("Array elements: \n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
            printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
            printf("\n");

    // Call child function that calculates memory address
    // returns address of chosen row or column from array
    // Integer values occupy 4 bytes of space
    int arr(int i, int j, int ncolumns, arr); 

    }
```

Comment: 1) Enable all compiler warnings.  2) To ask for the input row and column, try `scanf("%d%d", &i, &j);`.

Comment: *"would prefer to use shift logical instead of multiplying."* Turn on optimizations, and the compiler will do that for you.

Comment: `int arr(int i, int j, int ncolumns, arr);` declares a function called `arr`, which will of course clash with your actual array also called `arr`. And an "address" might not fit in a plain signed `int` type. Besides, what's wrong with just `printf("Address of arr[i][j] = %p\n", (void *) &arr[i][j]);`?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And for a [mcve] you don't need user input, hard-code values and input. And please tell us the expected output for some sample "input" (which as mentioned should be hard-coded).

Comment: `int arr(int i, int j, int ncolumns, arr);` is the _declaration_ of the function, not the call. The call would be: `arr(i, j, ncolumns, arr);` And the warnings of your compiler would reveal a lot...